# Query mysql from json came from angularjs - Python

Tags: python, json, angularjs

Hi Guys I already get the json data and this is my json data from angularjs, can someone help me on this?. I'm stuck only on it. Thank you.

```
{u'isChecked': {u'49871': False, u'49870': True, u'113634': False}}
```

then in my python I want to update mysql when id is found in the json data

right now here is my code for updating and i want to connect it to my json data

```
   updatetable = """UPDATE table_x
                                 SET value = '1'
                                """
        db.session.execute(updatetable)
        db.session.commit()
```

Comment: This is completely unclear. What does that dictionary have to do with the SQL? *How* do you want to connect them? Where are you having problems?

Comment: the dictionary came from json are the list of id's where I want to update in mysql. If the id is found in json and it is true, i want to update my value to be 1 in my mysql table.

Comment: OK, and what do you have so far?

Comment: So in example you have provided you should update record for id=49870:
UPDATE table_x SET value = '1' where id=49870;
Is that correct?

Comment: hi @gandra404 yes that is what i want. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import platform
import sys
import urllib2
import simplejson as json

def update_table(id):
    sqlUpdateStr = "UPDATE table_x SET value = '1' where id="+id
    print "Executing update: " + sqlUpdateStr

def test_parse_json():
    print "Loading json ..."
    req = urllib2.Request("http://localhost/example.json")
    opener = urllib2.build_opener()
    f = opener.open(req)
    # json.load() will deserialize your JSON document and return a Python object.
    data = json.load(f)

    print data['isChecked']
    print ""

    for id in data['isChecked']:
        id_val = str2bool(data['isChecked'][id])
        if id_val == True:
            print "Found id for update: " + id
            update_table(id)
        else:
            print "Ignoring record with id=" + id

def str2bool(v):
    return v.lower() in ("yes", "true", "t", "1")

def main():
    test_parse_json()

    return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and the content of example.json is:

```
{
    "isChecked":{
        "49870":"true",
        "49871":"false",
        "113634":"false"
    }
}
```